# Can I make PayPal release pending balance on personal payment sooner than 30 days?

Tags: australia, paypal, electronic-payment, croatia

My uncle and my brother sent me some money over paypal recently, but it says I have to wait 30 days to receive it. It was made as personal payment.

Is there any way to get that money any faster? I have just recently activated my account to recieve payments, but still. This kind of defeats the purpose.

My brother is from Croatia, same as me but our uncle currently resides in Australia if this helps.

Comment: And where are you at?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this is to prevent fraud, and there is likely nothing (through paypal) that you can do to speed up the process apart from making sure you verify all the accounts linked to PayPal (bank, credit, etc) and that your relatives do the same.

Be mindful that Paypal is NOT intended as a large sum transfer service - they are a convenience for online payments. Using an established monetary transfer system (wire, etc) for this purpose in the first place would have saved some time at the expense of a convenience fee.

Tax implications, etc all apply, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can speed up the process. Tell the person sending you the money, to log in in to their Paypal account and to click "confirm receipt" next to transactions related to their sending to you. After this, the money will be relased immedidiately.

Answer (score 0):

you can actually send them an email and they will lift the pending balance.
I have tried it and they were able to help me.
Goodluck